# Why do I get the ArrayStoreException?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have a two dimensional array:

```
private BigInteger[][] keysArray = new BigInteger[2][128];
```

A key generator:

```
public BigInteger keyGenerator(int k) {
        SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
        BigInteger bg = new BigInteger(k, srandom);

        return bg;
}
```

and this method:

```
public void setKeysArray() {
        Arrays.fill(keysArray, keyGenerator(k));            
}
```

I get the `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` and I don't understand why.

Comment: `keysArray` as a 2D array. What you want to fill is the array `keysArray[something]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this «explanation» of a two-dimensional array like `new BigInteger[2][128]`:

> BigInteger[number of arrays][how many elements in each of those arrays]

This means, you are trying to store a `BigInteger` where an array is expected. This results in an [`ArrayStoreException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) when `Arrays.fill` tries to assign the values of type `BigInteger`.

Inside your `setKeysArray` method you need to reference and fill the two arrays of `BigInteger`s separately with indices `0` and `1`:

```
Arrays.fill(keysArray[0], keyGenerator(k));
Arrays.fill(keysArray[1], keyGenerator(k));
```

After that you have two arrays, each one holding the same `BigInteger` 128 times. All good, if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem storing big interger. you have pass integer instead of big integer.

Thrown when a program attempts to store an element of an incompatible type in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an array of arrays when you do

```
private BigInteger[][] keysArray = new BigInteger[2][128];
```

meaning you have two arrays of 128 BigIntegers.

If you want to fill the matrix completely, you should call `Arrays.fill(keysArray, keyGenerator(k));` like you did, but twice; once for each array of arrays you have.

Answer (score 0):

since `keysArray` is a 2d array which means it's an array that contains other arrays so this  `Arrays.fill(keysArray, keyGenerator(k));` won't work.

instead you have to fill the individual `keysArray` elements like this :

```
for(int i= 0; i < keysArray.length;i++) {
   Arrays.fill(keysArray[i], keyGenerator(k));
}
```